# FabricJS Fluid snap to grid

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'd like to use this `http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/` function where objects can be snapped to grid, the problem is that I don't want it to snap directly to the lines but when it is getting close to it only. so the movements of objects are fluid and it can be snapped if the user wants to.

Here is the code, I think it has to do with `Math.round()`:

```js
grid = 50;

// Grid display part
for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}

// Snapping part
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / 50) * 50,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / 50) * 50
  });
});
```

any suggestion on how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this small tweak should take care of it:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  if (Math.round(options.target.left / grid * 4) % 4 == 0 &&
    Math.round(options.target.top / grid * 4) % 4 == 0) {
    options.target.set({
      left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
      top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
    }).setCoords();
  }
});
```

(or get you going in the right direction, smooth and snaps-to on mouse up)

Here's the updated Plunker, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/q0xe7yfz/.

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: This example might be usefull for futur use, but it is not what I meant, the user should be able to not align to the lines if he wants to, the snap should occur when he comes close to the line, but if his shape/image/text is inbetween/not close to the line, then it shouldn't snap to grid.

Comment: I updated the code and the JSFiddle, is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh it's all good I removed the mouse up and it works ! Thanks, to bearing it with me !

Comment: Glad it worked out, and thanks for having a go yourself.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: @LiamPillay should be good now.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs it, here is a working snippet of [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42984547/9362411) since original fiddle is not working anymore.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});
var grid = 50;

// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }))
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#faa',
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  left: 300,
  top: 300,
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#9f9',
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  if (Math.round(options.target.left / grid * 4) % 4 == 0 &&
    Math.round(options.target.top / grid * 4) % 4 == 0) {
    options.target.set({
      left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
      top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
    }).setCoords();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Hiroyuki for the question and Tim and Emilio for the answer. Using this I have made snap to edge and snap to center code. I'm posting it here if in case anyone need it.

```
    let snap = true;
    let snapThreshold = 10;
    let grid = 50;

    canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
        // Snap to grid
        if (Math.round(options.target.left / grid * 4) % 4 == 0 &&
            Math.round(options.target.top / grid * 4) % 4 == 0) {
            options.target.set({
                left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
                top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
            }).setCoords();
        }

        // Snap to edges and center
        if (snap) {
            // Snap to left
            if (options.target.left < snapThreshold && options.target.left > -snapThreshold){
                options.target.set({
                    left: 0
                }).setCoords();
            }
            // Snap to right
            const w = canvas.getWidth();
            if ((options.target.left + options.target.width) < (w + snapThreshold) && (options.target.left + options.target.width) > (w - snapThreshold)){
                options.target.set({
                    left: w - options.target.width
                }).setCoords();
            }
            // Snap to top
            if (options.target.top < snapThreshold && options.target.top > -snapThreshold){
                options.target.set({
                    top: 0
                }).setCoords();
            }
            // Snap to bottom
            const h = canvas.getHeight();
            if ((options.target.top + options.target.height) < (h + snapThreshold) && (options.target.top + options.target.height) > (h - snapThreshold)){
                options.target.set({
                    top: h - options.target.height
                }).setCoords();
            }

            // Snap to center of the canvas
            const w2 = canvas.getWidth()/2;  // half of canvas width
            const oW2 = options.target.width/2  // half of object width
            if ((options.target.left + oW2) < (w2 + snapThreshold) && (options.target.left + oW2) > (w2 - snapThreshold)){
                options.target.set({
                    left: w2 - oW2
                }).setCoords();
            }
            const h2 = canvas.getHeight()/2;  // Half of canvas height
            const oH2 = options.target.height/2;  // Half of object height
            if ((options.target.top + oH2) < (h2 + snapThreshold) && (options.target.top + oH2) > (h2 - snapThreshold)){
                options.target.set({
                    top: h2 - oH2
                }).setCoords();
            }
        }
    });
```